Visual Studio 2022 automatically enters overtype when midline
I genuinely think I'm going insane on this issue as it's such a small thing.
I am using Visual Studio 2022 (purple one) in my unity project.
As of updating to this version, ever since I have went midline in my code, the cursor automatically sets to overwrite mode, returning to normal only at the end of the code line.
I have pressed insert on my keyboard, tried the on-screen keyboard doing the same all to no avail. Is this a feature or ?
All help is appreciated!
Edit - I have just discovered if I double click on a whitespace or space midline it will go to the default cursor, this doesn't work mid word however as it highlights the word.

have you installed something like copilot or other AI code assister?

@BugFinder , I myself haven't installed any and nothing appears in the extensions area of visual studio. However I have noticed some better code suggestions since updating that weren't in the previous version (2019) which I can add by clicking tab, not sure if this counts as a "AI code assister"

i dont think vs22 would have it without it being mentioned , only reason i ask is Ive had a few arguments with copilot or other AI things when trying them for a laugh in that sometimes you cant press even space without it filling in half a class of bs you never asked for, so it messed with me hard - hence.. oddly uninstalled...

Ah thanks for the info, I have a feeling its a setting or something that I have accidentally turned on (or is on by default but I can't find much on it so I doubt it). I looked through the settings and I have IntelliSense as part of the C# install. Nothing in its settings about overtype and auto switching though. Think this may be the culprit?

remapped a key somewhere?

It appears to have resolved itself now (I have re-opened the workspace to begin working today)

After re-loading the workspace today, I found the issue resolved. I believe I accidentally turned on overwrite mode in my cursor using a key bind other than insert (I have found keybinds such as ctrl-shit-i or shift-o working for some other people) by accident.
Then when trying to resolve the issue by pressing the instert key on my keyboard it didn't switch it back as I previously removed the insert key keybind in Visual Studio 2019 (Kept accidentally clicking it on my old keyboard), which I assume was saved when updating to 2022.
So if you find yourself having the same issue, maybe check these things.
Cheers to all who helped :)
